# iloc syntax error when trying to insert multiple index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want it to get the index from 0 to 18 instead of typing it out manually. I tried using this but i got a syntax error.

```
dep=dep.iloc[:,[0:18]]
```

this is the full code below

```
dep=df.groupby(['Serious,Critical','ActiveCases','TotalTests','TotalCases','TotalDeaths','TotalRecovered','NewCases','NewDeaths','NewRecovered','New Cases/1M pop','New Deaths/1M pop','Active Cases/1M pop','1 Deathevery X ppl','1 Testevery X ppl','1 Caseevery X ppl']).count()
dep=dep.reset_index()
dep=dep.iloc[:,[0:18]]
dep.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is without brackets:

```
dep.iloc[:,0:18]
```

Or, if you want to include 18:

```
dep.iloc[:,0:18+1]
```

Brackets would be used to pass a list of columns to index. For instance `dep.iloc[:,[0,18]]` would take columns `0` and `18` but not those in between.